# invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript on 2d matrix using 4 for cycles

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, for-loop, matrix

i'm trying to Parallelize a convolution blur effect on images, so i'm using opencv.

everything was working fine until i try to make the kernel size variable.

to do that i created a 4 nested for cycles, the first 2 for cycles to go over the image data matrix (m), an the other 2 for cycles to get the RGB values in m of the the neighbors of (i,j), (matrix with size kernel*kernel)
then a get the next errors for every line where i'm getting RGB data with parameters l,m.

in my older version with static kernel size (only 2 for cycles), not a single error or warning and i really dont understand why.

```
$ g++ blurh.cpp -o blur `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -lpthread
blurh.c: In function ‘void* blur(void*)’:
blurh.c:53:16: error: request for member ‘at’ in ‘m’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
       sumB+=(m.at<cv::Vec3b>(l,m)[0] );
                ^~
blurh.c:53:28: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
       sumB+=(m.at<cv::Vec3b>(l,m)[0] );
                            ^
blurh.c:53:36: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
       sumB+=(m.at<cv::Vec3b>(l,m)[0] );
                                    ^
```

function code for every pthread

```
void *blur(void *ap2){
    info *ap=(info *)ap2;
    int start, end, i;
    start = ap -> start;
    end = ap -> end;
    int w = ap -> w;
    cv::Mat m = ap ->m;
    int kernel = ap->k;

    int sumB=0;
    int sumG=0;
    int sumR=0;

    int deno=(kernel*kernel)-1;

  for (i = start+(kernel/2); i < end-(kernel/2); ++i)
  {
    for (int j = 1+kernel/2; j < w+1; ++j)
    {
        sumB=0;
        sumG=0;
        sumR=0;
        for (int l = i-(kernel/2); l < l+(kernel/2); ++l)
        {
            for (int m = j-(kernel/2); m < m+(kernel/2); ++m)
            {
                sumB+=(m.at<cv::Vec3b>(l,m)[0] );
                sumG+=(m.at<cv::Vec3b>(l,m)[1] );
                sumR+=(m.at<cv::Vec3b>(l,m)[2] );
            }
        }
        sumB-=(m.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0] );
        sumG-=(m.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[1] );
        sumR-=(m.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[2] );

        m.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0] = sumB/deno;
        m.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[1] = sumG/deno;
        m.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[2] = sumR/deno;

    }
  }
  cv::imwrite( "testedH720.jpg", m);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
blurh.c:53:16: error: request for member ‘at’ in ‘m’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
       sumB+=(m.at<cv::Vec3b>(l,m)[0] );
```

Read the error message. The `m` in the specified lines is of type `int`, and as such it does not have any members that you could access via `operator.`:

```
        for (int m = j-(kernel/2); m < m+(kernel/2); ++m)
        //------^^^
        {
            sumB+=(m.at<cv::Vec3b>(l,m)[0] );
            sumG+=(m.at<cv::Vec3b>(l,m)[1] );
            sumR+=(m.at<cv::Vec3b>(l,m)[2] );
        }
```

That `int m` of the loop shadows the `cv::Mat m`.

Answer (score 0):

Error message is quite clear. You have redefined the variable name `m` inside the `for(...)` loop. Earlier it has been defined in line number of 7 of given code snippet.

```
cv::Mat m = ap ->m;
```

And you redefined `m` again over here

```
for (int m = j-(kernel/2); m < m+(kernel/2); ++m){
    // Do Something
}
```

Rename the `m` defined in above `for(...)` loop to fix your problem.